# StructureMap Tutorial

Tags: structuremap

I am look for some Structure map Tutorials.

Does anyone know of any?

EDIT: All answers are appreciated but I was looking for something that is not on the first 2 pages of Google. I would have the sense to do that first.

Comment: I understand Ted, when I started with structure map I found that to be enough, and when I needed new uses most were found on links from that page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/QuickStart.htm.
And from there you can find info of plenty of different usages.

**Update 1:** I had been using structuremap, and the info in there was just enough to get it going. Also note that I am biased for text formats, although I do listen/watch other formats from time to time. That said, here are some extra info on it that I have read/watched:

- This web cast of the http://wekeroad.com/2008/06/03/mvcstore-part-13/ (as I watched the whole series) - this one got me into looking at structuremap
- Blog Posts by chad myer on:
  http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/tags/StructureMap/default.aspx
- This blog post on structuremap profiles http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/08/13/contextual-binding-with-structuremap-2-5.aspx
- Some of the posts by jeremy miller on http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/tags/StructureMap/default.aspx

Comment: All links except for the devlicious blog post are broken.

Answer (score 7):

The best examples I found are on [DimeCasts](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/StructureMap)